# Populating a dropdownlist with enum

Tags: c#, html, dropdown

I am trying to populate a dropdown list with `enum` values but I am running into issues. This is my class

```
public class Project
    {
        ...
        public Currencies Money { get; set; }

        public enum Currencies
        {
            [Display(Name = "Euro")]
            Euro = 1,
            [Display(Name = "USD")]
            USD = 2
        }
```

and this is my view

```
@model Projects.Domain.Project

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<br />
<p style="font-weight:bold;">Add new project</p>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">            
            <div class="form-group">
                <select asp-for="Money" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Currencies>()"></select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

but I am getting an error saying `The type or namespace currencies could not be found.` It's the same if I substitute `Currencies` with `Money`. What is the correct way to populate the dropdown list?

Comment: Either use the fully qualified name of `Currencies`, or add a using statement for it's namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with Full name: `Projects.Domain.Project.Currencies`

Select code:

```
 <select asp-for="Money" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Projects.Domain.Project.Currencies>()"></select>
```

Or with Using namespace:

```
@using Projects.Domain
```

Select code:

```
 <select asp-for="Money" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Project.Currencies>()"></select>
```